# VSC won´t find pygame even when I just installed it

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I´ve installed and uninstalled pygame several times, I tried with pip/pip3 and still appears the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\josel\Desktop\Programación\Python\pygame\test\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I also executed "pip install pygame" in the vsc terminal and gave this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\josel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (2.0.1)
```

Edit:

The output of

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

is:

```
['c:\\Users\\josel\\Desktop\\Programación\\Python\\pygame\\test', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\josel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: Please add `import sys; print(sys.path)` to your Python script and post the output. You might have multiple versions of Python installed. Also, do you run your main.py from within VSC?

Comment: I added the output, and yes, I execute the code directly on vsc

Comment: As you can see, the folder where pygame is installed isn't in the path. So either install pygame outside of VSC or run the game from within VSC, using the Python version where pygame is installed.

Answer (score 1):

A short way to fix this is using a `venv`

```
python3 -m venv venv
source ven/bin/activate
pip install pygame
```

keep the `venv` activated when you run the code

use

```
which python # check if VSC is using the right interpreter
```